# Spring Batch StoredProcedureItemReader cursor data type

Tags: spring-batch

I am planning to use StoredProcedureItemReader provided by Spring Batch to call a stored procedure in SQL Server. For the configuration, we need to pass the datatype for the cursor returned (OUT PARAMETER) by stored procedure.

In oracle it is oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR. What is the corresponding type for SQL Server ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen so far, the possible types are listed here :

- Java 6 : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html
- Java 7 : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html
- Java 8 : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html

Java 6 & 7 don't have any type matching cursors, but Java 8 has `REF_CURSOR`.

Also, it seems like JDBC doesn't support `CURSOR` as an `OUT Parameter` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108(v=sql.110).aspx